# my lxc machines will not start

Tags: juju, lxc

I am trying to set up a local Juju environment, so I followed the official instructions on https://jujucharms.com/docs/1.25/config-LXC, on a machine running trusty that was installed via MAAS.

the problem that I am having is that the machines aren't automatically starting.

I ran juju status. Here is the output:

```
environment: local
machines:
  "0":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.20.14.1
    dns-name: localhost
    instance-id: localhost
    series: trusty
    state-server-member-status: has-vote
  "1":
    instance-id: pending
    series: trusty
  "2":
    instance-id: pending
    series: trusty
  "3":
    instance-id: pending
    series: trusty
  "4":
    instance-id: pending
    series: trusty
services:
  mysql:
    charm: cs:trusty/mysql-14
    exposed: false
    relations:
      cluster:
      - mysql
      db:
      - wordpress
    units:
      mysql/0:
        agent-state: pending
        machine: "2"
  nagios:
    charm: cs:trusty/nagios-1
    exposed: false
    units:
      nagios/0:
        agent-state: pending
        machine: "3"
  owncloud:
    charm: cs:trusty/owncloud-2
    exposed: false
    units:
      owncloud/0:
        agent-state: pending
        machine: "4"
  wordpress:
    charm: cs:trusty/wordpress-1
    exposed: false
    relations:
      db:
      - mysql
      loadbalancer:
      - wordpress
    units:
      wordpress/0:
        agent-state: pending
        machine: "1"
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should take a look at the log files in /var/log/juju to see if anything stands out.

Comment: thanks, checked the logs, turned off ufw, and it was fixed

Comment: Great, might be worth updating the question and adding an answer for others who may run into a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to turn the firewall (ufw) off

```
sudo stop ufw
```

the machines then auto-provisioned.